# BLE advertisement watcher- How to get the data

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

I want to make a program (UWP) that watching for BLE advertisements. I used the same code of "Windows-universal-samples" that watching for all LE advertisements and displaying them in a list.
But I want a way to read the data or messages in the advertisements. 
Can anyone help me please?
thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 27/01**

Hello,
I tried an application  that can be used as an advertiser. I ran the program but I got the following result:

```
[04:28:03.265]: type=ConnectableUndirected, name=, manufacturerData=[], Message=""
```

I don't know why I can't read any data by my code!
Please can anyone help me!

Answer (score 3):

> But I want a way to read the data or messages in the advertisements.

You could create a Bluetooth LE Advertisement watcher, set a callback, and start watching for all LE advertisements.

```
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
watcher.Start();
```

If you have received Advertisement, And the below `manufacturerSections` is the list of manufacturer specific data sections in a BlutoothLEAdvertisement, you could process it in the `OnAdvertisementReceived` event handler like following.

```
var manufacturerSections = eventArgs.Advertisement.ManufacturerData;
if (manufacturerSections.Count > 0)
{
    // Only print the first one of the list
    var manufacturerData = manufacturerSections[0];
    var data = new byte[manufacturerData.Data.Length];
    using (var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(manufacturerData.Data))
    {
        reader.ReadBytes(data);
    }
    // Print the company ID + the raw data in hex format
    manufacturerDataString = string.Format("0x{0}: {1}",
        manufacturerData.CompanyId.ToString("X"),
        BitConverter.ToString(data));
}
```

For more you could refer to [Bluetooth LE Advertisements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/ble-beacon) documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  But if there is an android device that publishing an advertisement, and the advertisement contains a string message. and I want in my windows 10 application to read that message. How can I do that?

Comment: The above is an universal process, you could also use it to receive android advertisement within Windows 10 device

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT old question and answer, but I try anyway. Im running the same code as you have, but the ManufacturerData is always an empty list. When I use an app (nRF Connect) on my phone, I can see the advertisements and Manufacturer Data just fine. The code picks up some other random advertisements from other devices, and they contain data. Any idea what my problem may be?